# Sitefinity - How to filter News by Related Data field with Odata?

Tags: web-services, odata, sitefinity

I'm using the built in Web Service API in Sitefinity 10.
I tried to filter all news items by their related data item/items with Odata, but it seems that it could not be done.

```
~/api/default/newsitems?$expand={related-data-field}&$filter={related-data-field}/any(c: c/Id eq 888ac18a-85c0-4259-9a3c-05f25e53b23e)
```

With such a query I get an error with ***"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type"*** message.

Is it even possible to filter by related data item with Odata in Sitefinity? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about it's possibility but i know if you are using related items you have to check that type too when setting up the web service. Did you do that?

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine pointed out that Navigational properties of related types are not supported yet for filtering.

https://docs.sitefinity.com/manage-the-properties-of-a-type

Comment: Thanks, Jon. We are looking forward to have this functionality.
For now we implemented a workaround.

Comment: We added an event listener in the EventHub for IDataEvent.
`EventHub.Subscribe<IDataEvent>(Content_Action);`
On Update we get the related data items Id's and store them in a long text field, or an array of guids.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported with version 14.2.7921.0 of Sitefinity